# Would this question on which package managers can transfer packages over BitTorrent be considered off-topic for this site?

Tags: discussion, scope

I was about to ask this question "Which package managers can transfer packages via BitTorrent?" on Unix & Linux SE but I hesitated in posting it. See I thought that maybe it would be considered to have too many answers for it to be acceptable to this site.

Comment: Curious what you're trying to accomplish with the question—are you looking for a package managers for a particular distribution (which I guess would probably be OK, most distros only have one or two) or for *any* package manager for anything on any Unix-like OS? (And if the latter... why?) [It's possible I've just posted an answer as a comment... please let me know if you were thinking of the one-distro case in which case I'll convert to a proper answer.]

Comment: On any Linux distro. I am asking because if there is such a distro with a package manager that can transfer packages via BitTorrent I would like to give it a try.

Answer (score 5):

It seems you'd be asking a pretty broad question, except that I think the answer is "Debian [tried](https://wiki.debian.org/DebTorrent), it [didn't work out](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=730459), no one else is crazy enough."

If you want to ask anyway, you need to keep the question as narrow as possible, so it's actually answerable:

- Limit it to Linux distributions at least. The more you limit it, the more answerable it becomes.
- Explain why you want to download packages over BitTorrent. Practical problems tend to get better answers (including, possibly, some different solutions that you never thought of) than "sounds like it'd be cool".
- Be aware of existing related stuff, and mention it as appropriate. E.g., you can get CD/DVD/Blu-Ray/etc. images for most distros via BitTorrent. Or (for the case when you want to save bandwidth updating your dozens of machines), many package managers have caching solutions so you only download the package once, then the cache serves it to the other *n* machines.

You could also consider asking on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), if you can make your question fit their rules.